# Calculate Refill on Daily Usage

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data for daily usage like below.

[image]

I need to refill the product for every **2000** usage. This is expected result.

[image]

I try to use `SUM OVER` query to get daily total previous usage and try to divide to get multiple 2000.

```
SELECT Date, Usage,
       SUM(Usage) OVER(ORDER BY Date) AS DailyTotal,
       CAST(SUM(Usage) OVER(ORDER BY Date) / 2000 AS INT) Div
FROM Transaction
```

[image]

But, I still cannot find at what date I have to refill. How can I do something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use `LAG` window function with a subquery.

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
create table [Transaction]([Date] date, usage int);

insert into [Transaction] values
('2017-01-01',1373),
('2017-01-02',1387),
('2017-01-03',1509),
('2017-01-04',1523),
('2017-01-05',1537);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT Date, 
       Usage,
       DailyTotal,
       (CASE WHEN LAG(Div,1,Div) OVER(ORDER BY Date) <> Div THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) div
FROM (
    SELECT Date, Usage,
           SUM(Usage) OVER(ORDER BY [Date]) AS DailyTotal,
           CAST(SUM(Usage) OVER(ORDER BY [Date]) / 2000 AS INT) Div
    FROM [Transaction]
)t1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f6c73f/3/0)**:

```
|       Date | Usage | DailyTotal | div |
|------------|-------|------------|-----|
| 2017-01-01 |  1373 |       1373 |   0 |
| 2017-01-02 |  1387 |       2760 |   1 |
| 2017-01-03 |  1509 |       4269 |   1 |
| 2017-01-04 |  1523 |       5792 |   0 |
| 2017-01-05 |  1537 |       7329 |   1 |
```

Comment: I have no Refill Field. Refill is the expected field I need.

Comment: What's your expect result from your sample data?

Comment: The second Image, Table with additional Refill column.

Comment: @VikiTheolorado Ok I got it you can try my edit answer :)

Comment: yes, `LAG` Function is working. Thank You. But your example use `LEAD` instead of `LAG` and its not working.

Answer (score 1):

try below using a `row_number() and comparison`

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a507c907aa2d7e4939de0be097ded69d)**

```
select *,case when DailyTotal<2000*(case when rn=1 then 1 else rn-1 end) then 0 else 1 end
as refill from
(
SELECT Dateval, Usage,
       SUM(Usage) OVER(ORDER BY Dateval) AS DailyTotal,
       row_number() over(order by dateval) rn
FROM t1
)AA
```

OUTPUT:

```
Dateval             Usage   DailyTotal  rn  refill
01/01/2017 00:00:00 1373    1373        1   0
02/01/2017 00:00:00 1387    2760        2   1
03/01/2017 00:00:00 1509    4269        3   1
04/01/2017 00:00:00 1523    5792        4   0
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't works. This works if refill happen everyday. But I want the refill only done if the total usage (today and prev day) pass 2000.

Comment: @VikiTheolorado, I've updated the answer - you can check now

Comment: Sorry @fa06, but it still not complete. At first and second refill it works, but not at third refill which have to happen at the fifth day.